# $(this) returns wrong element when Jquery event binded to an entire class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, this

I have several inputs that have the class `specifierInput`

I want this function to run when any of those are focus'd on (it does)

```
$('.specifierInput').focus(function (e) {
    if (isValidationErrorResponse($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).trigger('keyup');
    }
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

Some of my HTML

```
<textarea id="mfpIdentifierText" name="ASSerialNumber" class="specifierInput"style="width:99%; height:80px; resize:none;"><%= (Session["ASSerialNumber"] ?? "").ToString()%></textarea>

<input name="ASModel" class="specifierInput alphaNumericWithSpacesCommasDashes" type="text" value="<%= (Session["ASModel"] ?? "").ToString()%>"/>
```

My issue is that `$(this)` is returning the first element that has the `specifierInput` applied to it, rather than the element that the event fired for.

Comment: you need to share the html.... it should be fine

Comment: Added some of the html that is relevant.

Comment: looks fine... can you help recreate the issue http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RdX4M/1/

Comment: Can't seen to recreate the issue here. I did a workaround and used e.currentTarget, but I'm not sure the side effects of using that.

Answer (score 1):

My version of jQuery is populating `this` with the element that fires the event, not necessarily the first element that meets fulfills the selector. Not sure why it's returning the first element for you.

In any case, you may want to see if the property `e.target` has the element you're looking for. From the jQuery API, `e.currentTarget` is not always the initiating element, but can be modified due to event bubbling. `e.target` will always be the initiating event.

[jQuery event.target API](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score 0):

Look towards the jQuery Proxy here  : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/

A proxy will set the right 'this'.